# Best practices to use rundeck scm for multi-environment

Tags: rundeck

**What would be the best practices to use Rundeck SCM plugin for multi-environment ?**

The current environment we have are PROD, DR, STAGE, TEST, DEV. We had setup rundeck instance for each environment and turn on SCM plugin for job definition. We use Gitlab as our source control platform.

In Gitlab, we have branches labeled as "prod", "dr", "stage", "test" and "dev". For DEV and Test environment, we turn on both IMPORT and EXPORT in SCM. For others, we only turn on IMPORT option since we want to enforce and restrict the job definition.

Every time when we finish development, we merge changes from dev/test -> stage -> prod/dr and pull the job definition from the SCM.

If anyone have any other suggestions and would like to share, that would be very helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Rundeck as orchestration tool or build tool? I would rather like to suggest an idea about creating jobs. Stack your common jobs together and keep as library and call them with your other jobs as the back end. It will save a lot of time as your environment becomes complex.